# How to pass array parameter to includes method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two arrays:

```
const tags=["filter1","filter2","filter3"]
const data = [{name:"aaaaa",tags:["filter1","filter2","filter3","filter4"]},{name:"bbbb",tags:["filter"]}]
```

I need something like this, but I can`t pass array into includes method

```
const newData = data.filter(i=>i.tags.includes(tags) === true) //[{name:"aaaaa",tags:["filter1","filter2","filter3","filter4"]
```

Comment: The [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method determines whether an array includes a _certain value_ among its entries, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate. (Not multiple values)

Comment: You are going to have to use some() or every() based on how you want it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want either one of these two:

```
const newData = data.filter(d => tags.every(t => d.tags.includes(t)));
const newData = data.filter(d => tags.some(t => d.tags.includes(t)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const data = [
  {name:"a", tags:["filter1", "filter2", "filter3", "filter4"]},
  {name:"b", tags:["filter5"]},
  {name:"c", tags:["filter6"]},
  {name:"d", tags:["filter3", "filter9"]}
];

const filterByTags = (arr, tags) => arr.filter(ob => ob.tags.some(tag => tags.includes(tag)));

console.log(filterByTags(data, ["filter3", "filter4", "filter6"]));
```

The above will return the Objects with *"name"* `a, c, d`:

- `a` because of `filter3` or either `filter4`
- (`b` **Not.** because has none of `filter3` `4` `6`)
- `c` because of `filter6`
- `d` because of `filter3`